# What is the difference between Choreo Internal Developer Platform Profile and Cloud Native App developer profile?

Tags: wso2, wso2-choreo

In Choreo there are five profiles,

- Cloud Native Application Developer
- API Management
- Devops
- IPaaS
- Internal Developer Platform

But it seems `Cloud Native Application Developer` and `Internal Developer Platform` are doing similar tasks. Is there any difference between those two ? Explanation regarding above is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you that there are indeed similarities between Choreo IdevP and Choreo Cloud Native App Developer (CNAD) profiles. However, there is one key distinction: while Choreo's IdevP is designed to group the activities involved in the overall project lifecycle, the CNAD profile focuses specifically on activities related to the application, leaving the building of dependent components to other team members.

IdevP profile is more relevant for features such as CIO dashboards and overall architecture. Although these profiles were created to help individual developers stay focused on their tasks, there is nothing preventing them from switching to a different profile if they wish to do so.

Interestingly, we have observed that some smaller development teams tend to default to the IdevP profile, while others have opted for a specific profile to simplify things for their developers.

Your feedback on these profiles is valuable as we continue to refine them. We are reviewing feedback from many developers to determine how we can best meet a range of needs. The goal is for each profile to provide an optimized experience for its use case. Please continue to share your thoughts on how we can improve the profiles and the overall developer experience on the [Choreo](https://wso2.com/choreo/) platform.

Comment: Is it possible to include clarifications similar to the above in below documentation ? https://wso2.com/choreo/docs/what-is-choreo/